# macbook pro 15 mid 2010 kernel panic el capitan

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I have a problem with my Macbook Pro 15 mid 2010.
This trouble appear when i run dota2

```
Anonymous UUID:       22155A9F-E13D-07C8-1412-473B25FC1E75

Sun Jul 10 13:03:56 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f85217bd5): "GPU Panic: [] 5 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff911ed42000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.12.8/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
```

```
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810c7cb630 : 0xffffff80020dab12 
0xffffff810c7cb6b0 : 0xffffff7f85217bd5 
0xffffff810c7cb790 : 0xffffff7f82d84fa4 
0xffffff810c7cb850 : 0xffffff7f82e51add 
0xffffff810c7cb890 : 0xffffff7f82e51b48 
0xffffff810c7cb910 : 0xffffff7f830d6a23 
0xffffff810c7cba80 : 0xffffff7f82e75b79 
0xffffff810c7cbaa0 : 0xffffff7f82d8bcfd 
0xffffff810c7cbb50 : 0xffffff7f82d89690 
0xffffff810c7cbd50 : 0xffffff7f82d8a891 
0xffffff810c7cbe30 : 0xffffff7f82d30a24 
0xffffff810c7cbe90 : 0xffffff7f851e4f91 
0xffffff810c7cbee0 : 0xffffff7f851e38a2 
0xffffff810c7cbf00 : 0xffffff800210f24a 
0xffffff810c7cbfb0 : 0xffffff80021c9017 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.12.8)[3186B630-FFF4-32C9-BAB9-DCD0C9DB6BA2]@0xffffff7f85209000->0xffffff7f8521cfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.12.8)[C57F5F56-2229-365F-9765-F24AA4687584]@0xffffff7f85201000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f82bb3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8216D61-5209-3B0C-866D-7D8B3C5F33FF]@0xffffff7f8292c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f82cd7000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[C49819CE-729A-36B2-9AC1-744A43DC236F]@0xffffff7f85204000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f82d2e000->0xffffff7f82fa3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8216D61-5209-3B0C-866D-7D8B3C5F33FF]@0xffffff7f8292c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[1114B99F-E439-329E-876D-1FEC4CF45DF6]@0xffffff7f82d1e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f82cd7000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[56199CA6-3C8D-3EBB-B5EF-7B1B4678ACF9]@0xffffff7f82fae000->0xffffff7f8325bfff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f82d2e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8216D61-5209-3B0C-866D-7D8B3C5F33FF]@0xffffff7f8292c000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(110.22)[D6F3F5F1-C1B0-31B1-9F5F-AF0A47F03B95]@0xffffff7f851e1000->0xffffff7f851f7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8216D61-5209-3B0C-866D-7D8B3C5F33FF]@0xffffff7f8292c000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(6.0.0d7)[4BEF649C-7CFD-31CA-8D84-1F0DB25BF60B]@0xffffff7f838f4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[1114B99F-E439-329E-876D-1FEC4CF45DF6]@0xffffff7f82d1e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f82cd7000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.12.8)[81C2784E-285A-38A7-A16E-515DCB816E0A]@0xffffff7f851da000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
```

```
Mac OS version:
15F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7E7B0822-D2DE-3B39-A7A5-77B40A668BC6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001f00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1232174237886
last loaded kext at 1119269064198: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7f85308000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 123313072896: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f83669000, size 126976)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.5f3
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.8
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.9
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.9
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B11, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x857F, 0x483634353155363446373036364700000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x857F, 0x483634353155363446373036364700000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.5f3 17904, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: ZTE_Technologies_MSM, Ethernet, en3
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: SanDisk SD8SB8U256G1122, 256,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: ZTE_Technologies_MSM
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Mac is suffering from a GPU panic there.
For your model there was a program by Apple to assist with replacing the affected component (the main board) but that has since ended.
See http://www.macworld.com/article/2062783/cures-for-a-panicking-mid-2010-macbook-pro.html

I am sorry to say but you will most likely need to replace your Mac with a newer equivalent Mac as your Mac has a serious hardware fault which can no longer be resolved. You can always get in touch with Apple to discuss your issue further and see if they can help you at all.
For your local support number see https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201232

Source: I am an Apple Certified Mac Technician